# How to check if array of array contains element

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of int array. I want to check if one int array exist in the collection

```
        var coll = new int[3][]
        {
            new[] {5, 5},
            new[] {4, 2},
            new[] {3, 4}
        };
        var valueToCheck = new int[] {4, 2};

        if (coll.Contains(valueToCheck))
        {
            // My logic
        }
```

but `coll.Contains(valueToCheck)` is returning `false`.
Can someone suggest what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The reason this returns `false` is because your `valueToCheck` is a different object instance than your original array of `{4, 2}`.  Despite the fact that the `int` values inside the arrays are equal, the arrays themselves are _not_ because you are asking whether that instance of your `valueToCheck` array is contained by `coll`.  It is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Any` combined with `SequenceEquals`. This will ensure that only the correct sequence is matched.

```
if (coll.Any(o => o.SequenceEqual(valueToCheck))) {
    // it exists!
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best/easiest way. But performance might be an issue with large arrays (of large arrays).